# Does the installer use cached downloads?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

When I use the [Nexus 7 installer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) , if I want to reinstall will the installer use cached downloads or will it redownload the images all over again?

Comment: Ok to answer my own question reflashing the Nexus7, the Nexus7 installer reports that images are already downloaded and asks if you want to reflash the already downloaded images or download again.

Comment: Should close ..

Answer (score 3):

The installer will re-use cached downloads.